# $_post inside a loop

Tags: php, html

i have 5 textboxes with the name of textbox1,textbox2 ... textbox5. now what i want is that instead of putting each of their value in a variable individually I want to do it in a loop, i have my code here but after i enter submit errors like

> Array to string conversion in ...

and

> Undefined index: textboxArray in...

.please see what's wrong with my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
        $sasa = $_POST["textbox".[$i].""];  
        $sql="INSERT into sasa (sasa) values('$sasa')";
        $q=$conn->query($sql);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You would be better off using an array of textboxes instead of numbered vars, but the issue is probably this: `$_POST["textbox$i"];`

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: replace this $_POST["textbox".[$i].""];   by $_POST["textbox".$i];

Comment: wait i'll try it first

Comment: the errors change but i guess its in my code, actually i am made an add and remove textbox with the use of jquery,. ill post my next question about it will look at it for me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line: `$sasa = $_POST["textbox".[$i].""]`;

You should do it as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(is_array($_POST["textbox"])){
        foreach($_POST["textbox"] as $sasa){
            //This is unsafe, use prepared statements instead
            $sql="INSERT into sasa (sasa) values('$sasa')";
            $q=$conn->query($sql);
        }
    }

}
```

This allows you to write your form like:

```
<form method="post" ... >

    <input type="text" name="textbox[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="textbox[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="textbox[]"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

In answer to your comment, this is how you could add/remove inputs dinamically using jQuery:

```
var control = $('<div class="controls"></div>');
control.append("<input class='form-control' type='text' name='textbox[]' placeholder='textbox'/><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a>");
control.appendTo('form');

control.find('.remove_this').click(function(){
    control.remove();
});
```

Comment: I agree. It is best to do it this way for a more dynamic/scalable system.

Comment: yeah, using `foreach` for avoid empty (not defined or field has removed by user) value for `textboxi`. but if the program should require five values, `foreach` so useless.

Comment: the values that are saved in the database are 0. why is that?

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan check your input names

Comment: actually i am using a dynamic add and remove textbox.

Comment: the input name is correct. it goes like this, .append("<div class='controls'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='textbox[]'  placeholder='textbox'><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a> <br> <br> </div");
        return false;
   }

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan take a look in my updated answer

Comment: jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        $("#append").click( function() {
     var control = $('<div class="controls"></div>');
    control.append("<input class='form-control' type='text' name='textbox[]' placeholder='textbox'><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a>");
    control.appendTo('form');
      return false;

    control.find('.remove_this').click(function(){
     control.remove();
    });
   }
   else{
    
   }
        });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();

Comment: return false;
        });
  });

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` print?

Comment: dont know, im still a begginer

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
    $sasa = $_POST["textbox".[$i].""];  
                             ^^^^
```

`[$i]` defines a new array with a single integer in it, which you then concatenate into a string. Arrays used in a string context simply become the literal word `Array`, which means you're effectively running this:

```
    $sasa = $_POST["textboxArray"];
```

which doesn't exist in your form.

You want

```
    $sasa = $_POST["textbox{$i}"];
```

instead. Note the `{}`.

And note that your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: do you really need braces `{}` if you are using double quotes `" .. "` ?

Comment: no, but it's a good habit to get into. `$x = 7; echo "$xyz {$x}yz";` kind of thing. one's an undefined var, the other spits out `7yz` as expected.

Comment: plus there's also php not having a greedy parser. if you try to echo out a multidimensional array in a `"`-quoted string, you get "wonky" behavior: `$x[0][1] = 'foo'; echo "$x[0][1]";` spits out `Array[1]`, because the parser stops after the first array dimension. you'd need `echo "{$x[0][1]}"`